# Checking Previous elements in a list with Python and based on the previous element store a value in a new column with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
list_Crashes = ['Startup', 'Crash in A', 'Shutdown', 'Crash in B', 'Crash in C', 'Startup', 'Crash in D',
                'Startup', 'Crash in E', 'Crash in F', 'Crash in G', 'Shutdown', 'Crash in X', 'Crash in Y', 'Crash in Z']
```

I have a table which contains 2 columns.
the code will check the previous element of list and look for ( Startup / Shutdown ) :
Example : if a Crash is after a Startup ; State column will be filled with Startup in front of that Crash as the table below :

| Crashes | State |
| --- | --- |
| Crash in A | Startup |
| Crash in B | Shutdown |
| Crash in C | Shutdown |
| Crash in D | Startup |
| Crash in E | Startup |
| Crash in F | Startup |
| Crash in G | Startup |
| Crash in X | Shutdown |
| Crash in Y | Shutdown |
| Crash in Z | Shutdown |

**the challenge I'm having is that the letters are random each time so i have to use  "Crash in" in my code and not specific letters !**

Any suggestions on how to do this?

**EDIT** : Real life example  ( each line is an element of a list) :

```
 12:33:04.1753    | Startup Configuration dazdazdazd
 12:35:15.0142    | Crash in A <546464>, thread 61
 12:35:53.0396    | Crash in B <5>, 3e9fc dazdazd
 12:35:54.1664    | Crash in C <70>,bfc690dasfff
 12:35:55.3817    | Crash in D <80>,de5484sdazdazd
 12:36:01.6642    | Crash in E <50>,bfc428fdsfsgdgsgsd
 12:53:34.6462    | System Shutdown
 12:53:48.1724    | Exception: Crash in Y <01>, 38310dazdazdafaga
```

**Code used from @mozway's Answer :**

```
def gen(lst):
    last_non_crash =''
    for x in lst:
        if  'Crash in' in x:
            last_non_crash = x
        else:
            yield [x, last_non_crash]
dataf = pd.DataFrame(gen(Crashtype), columns = ['Crashes', 'State'])
```

**Output :**

```
                                            Crashes                                              State
0   12:53:34.6462    | [1230.490] System shutdown\n   12:36:01.6642    | Exception: Crash in E<50>,...
```

**Expected Output :**

```
      Crashes     State
0  Crash in A   Startup
1  Crash in B   Startup
2  Crash in C   Startup
3  Crash in D   Startup
4  Crash in E   Startup
5  Crash in Y   Shutdown
```

Comment: It is still not clear to me with the example list you showed how you would like to associate shutdowns - to the elements before or after?. the following snippet for instance does not necessarily imply that crashes in F and G are associated with Startup : [...Startup, Crash in E, Crash in F ,Crash in G, Shutdown,..]

Comment: if a Crash is after a Shutdown ; State column will be filled with Shutdown in front of that Crash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can use a generator:

```
def gen(lst):
    last_non_crash = ''
    for x in lst:
        if not x.startswith('Crash in'):
            last_non_crash = x
        else:
            yield [x, last_non_crash]

        
pd.DataFrame(gen(list_Crashes), columns=['Crashes', 'State'])
```

output:

```
      Crashes     State
0  Crash in A   Startup
1  Crash in B  Shutdown
2  Crash in C  Shutdown
3  Crash in D   Startup
4  Crash in E   Startup
5  Crash in F   Startup
6  Crash in G   Startup
7  Crash in X  Shutdown
8  Crash in Y  Shutdown
9  Crash in Z  Shutdown
```

input:

```
list_Crashes = ['Startup', 'Crash in A', 'Shutdown', 'Crash in B', 'Crash in C', 'Startup', 'Crash in D',
                'Startup', 'Crash in E', 'Crash in F', 'Crash in G', 'Shutdown', 'Crash in X', 'Crash in Y', 'Crash in Z']
```

###### updated answer

```
import re

def gen(lst):
    last_non_crash = ''
    for x in lst:
        m = re.search(r'(Crash in \w+|Shutdown|Startup)', x)
        x = m.group() if m else 'unknown'
        if not 'Crash in' in x:
            last_non_crash = x
        else:
            yield [x, last_non_crash]

        
pd.DataFrame(gen(list_Crashes), columns=['Crashes', 'State'])
```

output:

```
      Crashes     State
0  Crash in A   Startup
1  Crash in B   Startup
2  Crash in C   Startup
3  Crash in D   Startup
4  Crash in E   Startup
5  Crash in Y  Shutdown
```

Comment: Another (albeit it convoluted method) would be something like: `pd.Series(list_Crashes).str.extract('(?P<crashes>^Crash in.*)|(?P<state>.*)').assign(state=lambda v: v.state.ffill()).dropna(subset=['crashes'])`

Comment: @mozway , thank you for the answer , I see you used startswith() . is it possible to use contains() instead ? since it doesn't always starts with "Crash in" but it is guaranteed that "Crash in" will be the strng  before the name of the Crash.

Comment: @Jon interesting approach ;)

Comment: for some definition of "interesting" :p

Comment: @Ahmed yes you can use any condition you want, in this case use `'Crash in' in x`

Comment: @Jon interesting as it's a clever one, but I still prefer the generator that is likely more efficient ;)

Comment: @mozway I tried 'Crash in' in x but it gave me a different result from what i expected because I also forgot to mention that "Startup" and "Shutdown" can be inside a string

Comment: Why don't you provide a real life example?

Comment: I edited  my Question with a real life example as requested

Comment: Can you provide the matching output?

Comment: I just Edited the post with the Output and Code used

Comment: @AhmedSelmi I meant the output **that you would like** given the new input ;)

Comment: @mozway oh sorry ! done.

Comment: @Ahmed check the update

Answer (score 1):

```
def function1(x):
    return ' '.join(x[x.index('Crash'):x.index('Crash')+3]) if 'Crash' in x else ''

col2=df1.col2.str.split(' ')
Startup=col2.map(lambda x:'Startup' in x)
Shutdown=col2.map(lambda x:'Shutdown' in x)
Crash=np.where(Startup|Shutdown,False,col2.map(function1))
df1.assign(Crash=Crash).assign(State=np.select([Startup,Shutdown],['Startup','Shutdown'],None)).ffill()\
    .loc[Crash!=False]
```

out：

```
 Crashes     State
0  Crash in A   Startup
1  Crash in B   Startup
2  Crash in C   Startup
3  Crash in D   Startup
4  Crash in E   Startup
5  Crash in Y  Shutdown
```